# Данные из MySQL не успевают подтянуться для отработки в другой функции

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await, promise

В функции findGetObject я проверяю нет ли ключа dns в мапе mapDNS, если нет, то перехожу в функцию findNGDY, где достаю информацию по этому dns. Далее собираю строку. НО данные не успевают подтянуться и строка собирается с undefined. В java synchronize, которая не позволяет всем сломиться в функцию, пока одна не отработала. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отредактировать так, чтобы работало правильно? Почитал и про промисы и async/await не получается никак(

```js
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '10.240.96.13',
  user: 'tatasu',
  password: 'Tasu_2019'
});

let mapDNS = new Map();
let ngduAndCeh;

function findGetObject(dns, objectInformation) {
  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < resultAll.length; i++) { // берем объект с Тэгом по Серийному Номеру
      let ind = resultAll[i].parameter_description.indexOf(objectInformation);
      let mapValue = mapDNS.get(dns);
      if (ind >= 0) {

        if (mapValue == undefined) {  //
          console.log("value = undefind");
          // Если в Мапе нет данных по этому ДНС, то тащим из базы, иначе собираем строку
          findNGDY(dns);  
        }
        let itog = mapDNS.get(dns) + ", " + objectInformation + ", " + resultAll[ind].parameter_kod + "."; // собраю итоговую строку
        console.log(itog);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}


function findNGDY(dns) {
  console.log("sql connecting......")
  connection.query(sqlIntegration, dns, function(err, rows, fields){  
    if (err !== null) {
      console.error('Ошибка: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    ngduAndCeh = rows[0].department_name + ", " + rows[0].service_name;
    mapDNS.set(dns, ngduAndCeh); //Добавляем в Мапу ключ:значение
    console.log("добавили в мапу -- " +  mapDNS.get(dns));
  });
}

Результаты выполнения данного кода:

value = undefind
sql connecting......
undefined, ДНС-650,РВС-1,Уровнемер,Уровень межфазный, S04N00650U004N06D0013N01PAI__LIPI00.
value = undefind
sql connecting......
undefined, ДНС-650,РВС-2,Уровнемер,Уровень межфазный, S04N00650U004N06D0013N01PAI__LIPI00.
value = undefind
sql connecting......
undefined, ДНС-650,РВС-3,Уровнемер,Уровень межфазный, S04N00650U004N06D0013N01PAI__LIPI00.
value = undefind
sql connecting......
undefined, ДНС-11,РВС-1,Уровнемер,Уровень межфазный, S04N00650U004N06D0013N01PAI__LIPI00.
value = undefind
sql connecting......
undefined, ДНС-11,РВС-3,Уровнемер,Уровень межфазный, S04N00650U004N06D0013N01PAI__LIPI00.
value = undefind
sql connecting......
undefined, ДНС-11,РВС-4,Уровнемер,Уровень межфазный, S04N00650U004N06D0013N01PAI__LIPI00.
value = undefind
sql connecting......
undefined, ДНС-11,РВС-5,Уровнемер,Уровень межфазный, S04N00650U004N06D0013N01PAI__LIPI00.
добавили в мапу -- йййййййййй, ЦДНГ-1
добавили в мапу -- йййййййййй, ЦДНГ-1
добавили в мапу -- йййййййййй, ЦДНГ-1
добавили в мапу -- цццц, ЦДНГ-2
добавили в мапу -- цццц, ЦДНГ-2
добавили в мапу -- цццц, ЦДНГ-2
добавили в мапу -- цццц, ЦДНГ-2
```

Comment: У вас идет код:  
let mapValue = mapDNS.get(dns);  
т.е. вы у пустого map хотите взять значение.
А по скольку он пустой, у вас будет undefined.
К тому же, connection.query асинхронная функция.
Она вызовется, но значение в ваш mapDNS будет положение не сразу. А к примеру, через 5 секунд, или 10. К тому времени, вас цикл на 12 строке уже отработает.

Получается так, что пока ваша асинхронная функция на 34 строке запрашивает данные, ваш синхронный код на строке 12 уже заканчивает свою работу.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я понял так как вы и объяснили, но не понял как сделать так, чтобы код отработал последовательно. Можете подсказать?

Comment: раз вы взялись за Node.js, вам надо научиться работать с асихнронным кодом, и понять как работать с колбеками так, чтобы данные не терялись.  
А если коротко, то ваша функция findNGDY должна начать иметь два параметра, (dns, callback).  Где callback это ссылка на функцию. в 41 строке перед console.log вы можете вызвать callback(dns); И строка 20 преобразится следующим образом: **findNGDY(dns, function(dns) { let itog = mapDNS.get(dns) + ", " + objectInformation + ", " + resultAll[ind].parameter_kod + "."; });**

Comment: Ваш вывоз callback() произойдет в тот момент, когда данные, запрашиваемые на 34 строке уже будут получены, а значит мэп mapDNS не будет пустой.

Comment: Где-то читал что callback лучше не пользоваться, вместо них применять промисы, правда их я тоже не понял как в данном случае использовать.

Comment: Промисы это обёртка колбеков, позволяющая избежать "колбэкхэлл", и сделать код читабельный. В вашем же случае, вы не знаете ни того, ни другого. А значит стоит познакомиться для начала с колбеками, а потом уже учить промисы.

Comment: Я сделал так как вы сказали и это дает правильный результат, Спасибо! Только, как я понимаю, что код на 12стр быстро отрабатывает и все "потоки" встают в очереди на запрос в БД на 34стр и данные берет уже с БД а не из мапы. А хотелось бы чтобы в запрос в БД не осуществлялся по dns, если такой dns в мапе есть.. Или я не правильно понял происходящие тут процессы?

Comment: Ваш код написан таким образом, что данные из карты вы пытаетесь забрать ровно в тот же момент, когда вы эти данные запрашиваете. Если вы хотите, чтобы данные забирались из карты, то метод с циклом должен быть запущен только тогда, когда карта уже заполнилась. Таким образом вам надо менять логику работы всего участка кода из вопроса.